# Gradle failed to sync due to unresolved dependencies

Tags: android

I just downloaded the java jdk 12.0.2, I downloaded android studios 3.4.2 and it came with gradle 5.1.1 pre-installed. The very first time I tried to run gradle it failed to sync due to unresolved dependencies. Does anyone know what I did wrong? I thought I followed the YouTube tutorial verbatim but I cant even start to program.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.test:runner:1.2.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Are you syncing with working internet connection? because it requires internet connection if you're not having all dependencies offline with offline gradle setup.

Comment: That was pretty much the problem. For whatever reason my companies Firewall doesn't like when these sorts of apps try access the internet from a company computer, I had similar problem with github a few months ago. I ended up bringing my personal laptop to the office for dev work. Thanks for the the advice.

Comment: Hi, try this link https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#offline. It can be helpful.